# PHP Composition in OOP

Tags: php

Someone please make me to understand, with a small ex, if is possible, how the PHP composition is helping me in the PHP OOP. 
I looked on tutorials but I didn't understand too much. Even here I searched and most of the topics with the title php composition don't have anything inside about composition.
I read about composition in PHP Advance Programming by Larry Ullman, but he only mentioned this subject in the book, in just one proposition.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you understand the concept of Composition in other OOP languages apart from PHP?

Comment: No, I'm sorry, I studied only PHP and MySql.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition

Comment: maybe interesting? [Composition vs. Inheritance: How to Choose?](https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/composition-vs-inheritance-how-choose). Internet search was: 'oop composition vs inheritance'. add 'php' to the start for stuff more related? I have read it - I agree with it ;-/

Comment: Thank you Ryan. It is a very good example, with a good theory. I thought that will be more practical examples, too, because in this way you actually learn.